# Is this temperature report normal for an Intel Quad Core / Radeon

Tags: temperature

The name of the temp1 indicator in lmsensor is radeon-pci-0100 temp1 and the chip is radeon. Is this temperature correct?

[image: Temperature report]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please explain how your question relates to Ubuntu? Otherwise it’s off topic on Ask**Ubuntu**. Hardware question are on topic on out sister site [SU].

Comment: Also, why does the title of your question mention an Intel CPU whereas the body refers to a Radeon GPU?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is *absolutely* normal...

To add a bit more info: below 75°C is great, anything below 95°C is fine!  From 100°C and upwards it starts becoming dangerous...

**Low-quality reviewers:** that's all the OP asked!

Comment: Personally I'd keep it under 70C... 100C means **turn the darn computer off now**.

Comment: @heynnema: uodated.  100°C means boiling water and most BIOSes turn the computer off at 100°C...

Comment: Extended use at 70-95C will also result in much shorter lifespan of the computer... so 95C is not fine.

Comment: @heynnema Then please [edit] so it's to your taste...  **;-)  :P**i

Comment: Not me... giggle... I was just enjoying our conversation. Happy New Year!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51045/discussion-between-fabby-and-heynnema).